# Is there a way to modify http header in the .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to get the client ip from the x-forwarded-for header, but the content format in the header is IP:Port rather than just IP.
Is there a way to modify http header in the .htaccess file before it reaches my app?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't split the `:Port` off in your code? It's one line of PHP.

Comment: It's an extension for Joomla, they don't provide the source code